# How can I set values from the constructor of the parent class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, subclass, super

I need to create a generic class that is able to dynamically set values based on the properties of the child class. Here are examples:

```
export class EnderecoMobile extends ModelCore{

  id: string = ''
  cep: number = 1

  constructor(data){
    super(data)
  }
}

export class ComandadasMobile extends ModelCore {
  postId: number = 1
  id: number = 1
  name: string = ""

  constructor(data){
    super(data)
  }
}
```

so far i have developed the following code

```
export class ModelCore {

  constructor(data: any, canal?: string) {
    const device: RegExp = new RegExp(this.getDevice(), 'i');
    let string = this.constructor.toString().replace(/(\n|\r)/g, '');

    if (device.test(this.constructor.name)) {
        this.montaResposta(data, string)
    }
  }
  /**
   *
   * @returns retorna uma string com o tipo de dispositivo caso a classe seja criada espcificamente para mobile ou desktop.
   * Caso não seja identificado nenhuma das duas opções retorna null
   */
  private getDevice() {
    const regex = /(mobile|desktop)/i;
    const device = this.constructor.name.match(regex);
    return device ? device[0] : undefined;
  }

  private montaResposta(data: any, string: string) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof data[key] === 'object') this[key] = this.preencherObjeto(data[key], string);
      if (Array.isArray(data[key])) this[key] = this.preencherArray(data[key], string);
      else
        this.setaVariavel(data, key, string);
    });
  }

  private preencherArray(data: any, string: string): any {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(element => {
      if (typeof data[element] === 'object') {
        this.preencherObjeto(data[element], string);
      } else {
        if (Array.isArray(data[element])) { this.preencherArray(data[element], string) }
        else {
          let key = Object.keys(data[element])[0]; // Corrigido aqui
          this.setaVariavel(data[element], key, string);
        }
      }
    })
  }

  private preencherObjeto(obj: any, string: string) {
    return Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      this.setaVariavel(obj, key, string);
    })
  }

  private setaVariavel(data: any, key: any, string: string) {
    const js: RegExp = new RegExp(` this\.${key} `);
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) || js.test(string)) { this[key] = data[key]; } else { delete data[key] }
  }
}
```

if I pass an object in the EnderecoMobile class like:

```
{
  id: '2',
  cep: 57057102,
  number: '278'
}
```

the expected result is

```
{ id: '2', cep: 57057102 }
```

but the final result is

```
{ "id": "", "cep": 1 }
```

however if I pass an array in the ComandadasMobile class like:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
]
```

the final result is:

```
{
    "0": {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum"
    },
    "1": {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum"
    },
    "2": {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi"
    },
}
```

I've done several experiments and I haven't found any solution, can anyone help me? =/

I need to create a global class so that developers of other projects can inherit these characteristics and not worry about the return when calling services, because only the properties created in the child class will be returned.

Comment: From the OP's expected result ... `{ id: '2', cep: 57057102 }` ... after having put in ... `{ id: '2', cep: 57057102, number: '278' }` ... does this mean the OP wants the (generic) constructor to actively suppress any data which is not covered by the default keys of a child class?

Comment: And do I correctly assume that instantiating a `EnderecoMobile` type like `new EnderecoMobile({});` should return an instance with the following data structure ... `{ id: '', cep: 1 }`?

Comment: Please [boil the example down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the least necessary code, preferably provided as [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). For better comprehension the audience prefers a consistent English naming schema (e.g. sub-classes and super-class methods).

Comment: Regarding the so far provided sole answer, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

An approach which targets the guaranteed default data values of each sub-type would merge both the initially passed data and the sub-type specific default-data at the base/super-class level's construction time.

The vanilla implementation then could look like this ...

```js
class ModelCore {
  constructor(data, defaultData) {
    Object
      .assign(
        this,
        defaultData,
        structuredClone(data),
    );
  }
}

class EnderecoMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data = {}) {

    super(data, { id: '', cep: 1 });
  }
}
class ComandadasMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data = {}) {

    super(data, { id: '', name: '', postId: 1 });
  }
}

const endereco1 = new EnderecoMobile({});
const endereco2 = new EnderecoMobile({
  number: '278',
  foo: 'foo',
});
const endereco3 = new EnderecoMobile({
  id: '2',
  cep: 57057102,
  number: '278',
});

console.log({ endereco1, endereco2, endereco3});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... whereas for TypeScript one has to introduce the definition of a default data type ...

```
type defaultDataType = {
  id: string,
  name?: string,
  postId?: number,
  cep?: number,
}

export class ModelCore {
  constructor(data:Object, defaultData:defaultDataType) {

    Object.assign(this, defaultData, structuredClone(data));
  }
}

export class EnderecoMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data:Object) {

    super(data, { id: '', cep: 1 });
  }
}
export class ComandadasMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data:Object) {

    super(data, { id: '', name: '', postId: 1 });
  }
}
```

In case one in addition also wants to prevent unnecessary data (like `number: '278'` for `endereco3` or `number: '278', foo: 'foo'` for `endereco2`) of the initially passed configuration, by just sticking to the key/property limitation of the sub-type specific default-data, one has to change the first provided stack snippet code towards ...

```js
function getDefaultLimitedData(data, defaultData) {
  return Object
    .entries(defaultData)
    .reduce((result, [key, defaultValue]) => {

      const value = structuredClone(data[key]);

      return Object
        .assign(result, {
          [ key ]: value ?? defaultValue
        });

    }, {});
}

class ModelCore {
  constructor(data, defaultData) {
    Object
      .assign(
        this,
        getDefaultLimitedData(data, defaultData),
        
    );
  }
}

class EnderecoMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data = {}) {

    super(data, { id: '', cep: 1 });
  }
}
class ComandadasMobile extends ModelCore {
  constructor(data = {}) {

    super(data, { id: '', name: '', postId: 1 });
  }
}

const endereco1 = new EnderecoMobile({});
const endereco2 = new EnderecoMobile({
  number: '278',
  foo: 'foo',
});
const endereco3 = new EnderecoMobile({
  id: '2',
  cep: 57057102,
  number: '278',
});

console.log({ endereco1, endereco2, endereco3});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```